# Dynamic schema vs Metadata

Tags: c#, mysql, database, oop

I am in the process of designing a Windows application written in C#. The application uses a MySQL database as a storage back-end.

Basically, the application allows you to "design your own database" in the following sense:

- You may define categories, each of which may have zero or more  relevant properties.
- You may create a record in a category and fill-in values for each of the properties.

Categories may be nested. An analogy goes with OOP: a category and its properties form a "class" and a record placed in certain "class" is an "instance". The nesting itself is a form of "inheritance".

Hope I explained the background enough, if not, please do ask. I am trying to keep the question short enough.

I am considering two very different approaches for the data storage. I would like anyone to reason which solution is better and why, because I am out of ideas.

**Dynamic schema approach.** Dynamically change the tables in the database when properties are added or deleted. Every category will get a table that will hold all the records.

Pros: easier manipulate data, less queries, easy type checking, simple constraints

Cons: (I think it will be) hard to manipulate the tables (I will have to perfectly understand the scheme), how do I describe the scheme at all? (data structure stored in tables, will have to use table description code)

**Metadata approach.** Have tables such as `categories`, `properties` and `items`. Use a ton of auxiliary tables to store stuff.

Pros: feels cleaner, all setups will have the same database structure, simple future upgrades, simple data description

Cons: hard to write queries and manipulate data, may need stored procedures for reasonable performance

---

**Question aside - metadata approach.** If I want the properties to have a fixed data type (such as `string`/`int`/`datetime`) and I don't want to store everything as a damn string, I think it'll be best to have a table such as `int_property_value (id<PK>, property_id<FK>, record_id<FK>, value<int>)` for int params (where value is a reasonably sized int).

Is there a better solution? What about storing bytes directly in the database? (But again, that asks for problems, such as with endianess, unless I use some standard form of serialization.)

Comment: What you call "metadata approach" essentially tries to treat the database as a key-value store. It's not clean, not simple to update (think versioning)  and is *very* slow. A table is best considered as an entity (hence ER) and the database stores the entities' metadata in its system catalog. This isn't a new approach either, although it was superseded either by document databases for very dynamic schemas, or sparse columns. You should probably also check Model Driven Development, for techniques and/or frameworks for mapping models to databases

Comment: Thanks for answer. For integer properties, I will want to store min-max range of allowed values. How do I store this in the system catalog of the database? I think I will need to keep some metadata anyway, and I will end up syncing the intended scheme of the database and the actual scheme captured in the tables. What do you think?

Comment: You don't. You define tables, check constraints, aliases and types. Databases aren't hard-coded, you *can* modify them using DDL. Migrating the data is the real issue. Imagine you created what you describe. What would happen when you added a new property? What about existing entities? How is this **any** different than adding a column?

Comment: OK, I am not convinced for either solution, I want to keep my mind open to both approaches, that's why I'm asking (and I hope you don't mind me doing it). Still I don't see what do I have to do to (for example): offer the user a GUI for task such as "New Item In Category 'Computers'", with appropriate editor controls for each property ('Manuf.', 'Model', etc.) and validate inputs reasonably? I just don't believe I could get all the data from the database's system catalog. I would agree the "dynamic scheme model" is better if I only had an answer to this.